# Django project bug tracked with redmine, same users

Tags: django, git, redmine, openldap

I'm creating a project using Django.

For this project I use [git](http://git-scm.com/) and [redmine](http://www.redmine.org/).

I'd like to have the same users on my Django project as in redmine.

What do you suggest ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use LDAP for user authentication. [django-auth-ldap](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-auth-ldap/) is an LDAP authentication backend for Django, and [Redmine supports LDAP](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineLDAP) out of the box, so it should be easy peasy.